# OpenMPI process affinity

Tags: openmpi

When I do `mpirun --map-by node --bind-to numa --report-bindings ./out 26`, `--bind-to` option causes the following error:

> On Linux, lack of the functionality can mean that you are on a
>   platform where processor and memory affinity is not supported in Linux
>   itself, or that hwloc was built without NUMA and/or processor affinity
>   support. When building hwloc (which, depending on your Open MPI
>   installation, may be embedded in Open MPI itself), it is important to
>   have the libnuma header and library files available. Different linux
>   distributions package these files under different names; look for
>   packages with the word "numa" in them. You may also need a developer
>   version of the package (e.g., with "dev" or "devel" in the name) to
>   obtain the relevant header files.

`ompi_info | grep hwloc` shows:

> MCA hwloc: hwloc1117 (MCA v2.1.0, API v2.0.0, Component v3.0.0) MCA
>
> rtc: hwloc (MCA v2.1.0, API v1.0.0, Component v3.0.0)

So I guess processes affinity is supported. I have 26 dual core nodes and I want to use only 1 CPU per node. Why I can't bind processes?

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure Open MPI cannot bind processes ?

Note your command line tries to bind a MPI process to a NUMA domain (socket most of the time). If you want to bind to a core, then

```
mpirun -bind-to core ...
```

In order to check processes binding

```
mpirun -report-bindings ...
```

You might be able to set process affinity but not memory affinity because of a missing library.

```
 sudo yum install -y numactl-devel
```

should do the trick on RedHat based systems.
You will need to `configure` and `make install` after that.

Comment: I already tried `--map-by node bind-to core` but still it gave the same error. I will give feedback after installing the library you mentioned.

Comment: How can I bind to multiple cores for a rank?